# How to center child div when wider than parent div for email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm creating a custom email file through SendGrid. I'm trying to get my footer to span the whole width of the client, particularly for desktop. I'm given a single 600px column, thus my footer looks fine on mobile but thin on desktop.

I tried making my footer div's much wider (making it larger than it's well-centered parent) and giving it a negative left margin, which centers it perfectly. Sadly, Gmail disregards negative margins.

There are many other techniques around SO to center children, regardless of width, but none of them are valid CSS for email clients. Email CSS will not allow:

- position
- flex
- transform: translate

text-align: center is allowed and does the trick, but only if the child is thinner than its parent.

What other technique will allow me to center a child div when it's wider than its parent?

Note: more allowed/forbidden CSS can be found at https://www.caniemail.com/. It's caniuse.com for email clients.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

.wide-child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wide-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: caniemail.com is more up to date :)

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example? That would really help

Comment: @Nathan thanks! added your link and an example

Comment: Hmm this is very abstract and web-oriented the way you've presented it. Can you give a use-case? Email is often very hacky, and would depend on what sort of content you are dealing with: background images? Images? Just text? 
2. Also, do you actually need the content wider, or are you looking for a way to scale it appropriately for mobile and desktop? WHat's the actual issue?

Comment: I'm trying to get the background color of the footer to take up the whole width in desktop. The content itself (some img links and text) is irrelevant; it just needs to be centered.

Comment: @Nathan There's other workarounds for my specific case and other cases, I'm sure. I described one in my answer. However, I'd be interested to know if we have no choice but to work around it or if a way to center does exist given these restrictions.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are asking, since it sounds to me like you want to construct a broken layout? How about this: you want a background colour full width (e.g. 1500px), but the rest of the email sits at 600px, and it still needs to respond to mobiles. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in a practical workaround, I solved the footer problem by making my 600px column's width be 100% instead, making my footer as wide as the viewport, and centering the rest of the elements - there's visually no difference.

I am still interested in a solution to make the child element center while wider than its parent.